# Error while installing visual studio 2013 pro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I get this error when i try to install visual studio 2013 pro update 3 even after multipile restarts.
I am using windows 8.1.

Image of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpzrP.png

Error Log:
http://pastebin.com/9dpY0fzZ

Comment: The log doesn't say anything about the cause of this problem. Take a look at the answer to a similar question here, maybe it can help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/546f6efe-106c-46aa-98d7-c8c658adb75e/trying-to-install-vs2013-professional-on-windows-81-get-the-computer-needs-to-be-restarted-but?forum=vssetup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you have tried to install the program before and that it corrupted some files, try downloading a remover.

I have had this problem with programs like malwarebytes before so i hope this also works for you. (but beware of virussus :D)

Comment: Are there any removers available? If i have looked but i cant find any old files.

Comment: Try using a registery cleaner, or try using the uninstaller and look at what kind of messages it gives (if it doesn't work)